# How to dynamic map a nested loop in a Table with Conditions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, mapping

I'm trying to map my table with some conditions in React. My table has 12 columns (months of the year). I have a json response providing 'MM' numbers. I hard coded an array of 'MM' from ['01',...,'06',...,'12']

```
let monthNum = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']

// json response: month = ['01', '05', '02']

tableBody = (
                    <tr>
                        {monthNum.forEach((day, idx) => {
                            month.forEach((d,i) => {
                                if(d === day) {
                                    time = 'X'
                                    month.splice(d[i], 1)
                                }
                                else {
                                    time = 'O'
                                }
                            })
                            return <td>{time}</td>
                        })}
                    </tr>
                )
// Output: X X O O X X X X X X X X


// Expected Output:  X X O O X O O O O O O O
```

Perhaps there's an easier way in doing this and I'm just making it more complicated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.includes()` on your `month` to check if the current `monthNum` you are mapping with `.map()` is within your `month` array. If it is you can display `X` if, if it isn't you can display `O` like so:

```js
const MonthTable = () => {
  const monthNum = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
  const month = ['01', '05', '02'];
  
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
         {
           monthNum.map(m => <td>{month.includes(m) ? 'X':'O'}</td>)
         }
      </tr>
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MonthTable />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```